# JUnit: Your JAXP provider [gnu.xml.dom.JAXPFactory@1bba105] does not support XML Schema

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, junit, junit4

After migrating my JAVA EE app. (Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework) from Ant to Maven I have some errors executing the Junit test using

```
mvn clean install
```

curiously running the test from Eclipse everything is fine.

But using `mvn clean install`  I have thse errors from ..\target\surefire-reports

```
-<testcase name="testSendExpirationReachedNotification on testSendExpirationReachedNotification" time="0.001" classname="com.tdk.iot.services.EmailServiceTest">

<failure type="org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException" message="Parser configuration exception parsing XML from class path resource [com/tdk/iot/services/testServiceContext.xml]; nested exception is javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider [gnu.xml.dom.JAXPFactory@1bba105] does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 with Apache Crimson? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (or Java 1.5) for full XSD support.">org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Parser configuration exception parsing XML from class path resource [com/tdk/iot/services/testServiceContext.xml]; nested exception is javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider [gnu.xml.dom.JAXPFactory@1bba105] does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 with Apache Crimson? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (or Java 1.5) for full XSD support. at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404) at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334) at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243) at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.createApplicationContext(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:215) at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.loadContextLocations(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:192) at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.loadContext(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:172) at org.springframework.test.AbstractSpringContextTests.getContext(AbstractSpringContextTests.java:133) at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.setUp(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:101) at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:132) at org.springframework.test.ConditionalTestCase.runBare(ConditionalTestCase.java:79) at org.springframework.test.annotation.AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests.access$001(AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests.java:74) at org.springframework.test.annotation.AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests$1.run(AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests.java:179) at org.springframework.test.annotation.AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests.runTest(AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests.java:287) at org.springframework.test.annotation.AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests.runTestTimed(AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests.java:258) at org.springframework.test.annotation.AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests.runBare(AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests.java:176) at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110) at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128) at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113) at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124) at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243) at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238) at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83) at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157) at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136) at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.start(JUnit4TestRunner.java:81) at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.run(JUnit4TestRunner.java:69) at org.testng.TestRunner$1.run(TestRunner.java:682) at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1005) at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRunJUnit(TestRunner.java:713) at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:614) at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334) at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329) at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291) at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240) at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52) at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86) at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224) at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149) at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057) at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:61) at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:158) at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:169) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350) at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021) Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider [gnu.xml.dom.JAXPFactory@1bba105] does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 with Apache Crimson? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (or Java 1.5) for full XSD support. at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:102) at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:70) at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388) ... 51 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage at gnu.xml.dom.JAXPFactory.setAttribute(JAXPFactory.java:109) at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:99) ... 53 more Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider [gnu.xml.dom.JAXPFactory@1bba105] does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 with Apache Crimson? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (or Java 1.5) for full XSD support. at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:102) at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:70) at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388) ... 51 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage at gnu.xml.dom.JAXPFactory.setAttribute(JAXPFactory.java:109) at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:99) ... 53 more </failure>
```

JAVA_HOME variable

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\
```

The tests are located in `myApp\myAppWeb\src\test\com\tdk\iot\TestSuite.java`

Here an example of a test:

```
import org.springframework.test.annotation.AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class EmailServiceTest extends AbstractAnnotationAwareTransactionalTests {

    private static final String[] CONFIG_LOCATIONS = new String[] {
            "classpath:com/tdk/iot/services/testServiceContext.xml",
            "classpath:com/tdk/iot/config/testApplicationContext.xml",
            "classpath:com/tdk/iot/config/testDatabaseMessageSource.xml",
            "classpath:com/tdk/iot/controller/propertyeditors/propertyeditorsContext.xml" };
...

}
```

and the xml test files in

The tests are located in `myApp\myAppWeb\src\test\resources\com\tdk\iot\...`

Comment: What java version are you using ? Also, can you provide the value of JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Check if these files are in your "src/main/resources" directory.

How are you instantiating the Spring application context? Are you relying on relying on Spring's JUnit4 runner to do so?

Comment: answered in the desc.